# Quartz.NET not triggering when certain code is in a method

Tags: c#, azure, quartz.net, azure-worker-roles

I'm trying to set up Quartz.NET in an Azure worker role for scheduling a daily events. After much trial and error, I've found that the inclusion of one line of code *within the target method* is causing the event to not get triggered at all

Building off the [Quartz.NET example](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_3.html), I have an IJob class the the overridden Execute method (registered with a scheduler & trigger).

When the offending line (commented) is removed, I can hit the breakpoint on the Trace.WriteLine statement. With it present, the breakpoint will never be hit, and the output isn't present elsewhere.

The code:

```
public class MyUpdaterJob : IJob
{
    public MyUpdaterJob()
    {
    }

    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("-- Yay - Job called");

        // Removing this line will result in the breakpoint above being able to be hit
        MyUpdateWorker updateWorker = new MyUpdateWorker();

        var logDate = context.FireTimeUtc.Value.AddHours(-1);

        // [...]
    }
}
```

I'm at quite a loss as to what it might be evaluating that would cause it to not trigger this event. Any suggestions?

- The 'MyUpdateWorker' is in another library
- This is currently running as an Azure Worker Role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow - this was an odd one.

As a result of the 'organic' growth of this project, the library containing the IJob implementation was previously a console app, which I'd switched the output over to 'class library' a few weeks prior.

The Platform target was set to (any only had available) x86. Everything else was compiling as 'Any CPU', and probably 64 bit.

I recall I had to manually edit the .csproj file to update this, but once that former-console-project-now-library was set to Any CPU, it now triggers correctly!

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd check the constructor for your MyUpdateWorker() class to see if that all works ok, perhaps have a log at the diagnostic logs to see if you can something in there that would indicate the cause. Normally I see problems with missing libraries on Azure so perhaps there is a missing dependency.

Just a few things to check (only had two coffees this morning so I'm still warming up)